# Thymeleaf: Working on and editing a List consisting of reference attributes

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, view, thymeleaf

I am currently struggeling on how to send a List with my RoomDTO class and alter them in Thymeleaf.

My RoomDTO Class is defined as following:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class RoomDTO {

    long roomNumber;
    String roomCategory;
    //LocaleDate as String as key
    Map<String, String> roomStateDays;

    public RoomDTO(){

    }

    public static RoomDTO fromRoom(Room room) {
        RoomDTO roomDTO = new RoomDTO();
        roomDTO.roomCategory = room.roomCategory().categoryName();
        roomDTO.roomNumber = room.roomNumber();

        roomDTO.roomStateDays = room.roomStateDays()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        (RoomStateDay rsd ) -> rsd.date().toString(),
                        (RoomStateDay rsd) -> rsd.state().name()
                ));

        return roomDTO;
    }
}
```

I have a Map that maps a LocalDate (which Thymeleaf did not like, so I converted it to a String) to a status. Now I want to set the status in a thymeleaf view.

In my view, I select certain dates for different rooms and in a dropdown menu, I want to change the selection to a certain status. Since sending the list directly back did not work out well, I read that I could use a Wrapper Class to send the list back.
In the Controller, I put the list into the wrapper, and sent it as a ModelAttribute to the View.

Wrapper Class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class RoomsRequestWrapper {

  private List<RoomDTO> rooms;

  public RoomsRequestWrapper(List<RoomDTO> rooms) {
    this.rooms = rooms;
  }

}
```

And in the Controller:

```
    @GetMapping(VIEW_ROOMS_URL)
    public String viewRooms(Model model){
        List<RoomDTO> rooms = roomService.getAllRooms();
        //gets first day of current week
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        TemporalField fieldISO = WeekFields.of(Locale.GERMANY).dayOfWeek();
        LocalDate firstDayOfWeek = now.with(fieldISO, 1);
        firstDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek.minusDays(1);
        RoomsRequestWrapper roomsWrapper = new RoomsRequestWrapper(rooms);

        model.addAttribute("title", "Zimmerplan");
        model.addAttribute("firstDayOfSelectedWeek", now.with(fieldISO, 1));
        model.addAttribute("roomsWrapper", roomsWrapper);
        model.addAttribute("isCheckIn", false);
        return VIEW_ROOMS_VIEW;
    }
```

When being sent back, I either get an error that the mapping from String to List does not work or the list is just empty. Apparently Thymeleaf converts my list to a String attribute?

Error Code:

```
 WARN 4172 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor$1: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'roomsWrapper' on field 'rooms': rejected value [[at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@42db53d3, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@4e53cb18, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@79b61c3c, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@20b3ce56, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@386e5458, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@68355346, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@212bf580, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@1fd44e8d, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@555215bb, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@173fd334, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@69c6b3a6, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@54db2835, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@11e110d8, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@782ed7a3, at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO@24a91083]]; codes [typeMismatch.roomsWrapper.rooms,typeMismatch.rooms,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [roomsWrapper.rooms,rooms]; arguments []; default message [rooms]]; default message [Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

At this point I am really unsure, since I tried a lot of variations and every time I either get the convertion error or the list is just empty.

Room status per day displayed in a table cell:

```
<div class="day" th:each="day: ${#numbers.sequence(0, 5)}">
                        <td colspan="2" th:classappend="${room.roomStateDays.get(firstDayOfSelectedWeek.plusDays(day).toString())}">
                            <input hidden name="state" th:field="*{roomsWrapper.rooms[__${iter.index}__].roomStateDays[__${firstDayOfSelectedWeek.toString()}__]}">
                        </td>
                    </div>
```

Form to submit the changes:

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <form method="post" th:object="${roomsWrapper}" th:action="@{/rooms/updateroomplan}">
                        <input th:field="*{rooms}" th:value="${rooms}" hidden>
                        <a type="submit" class="dropdown-item" onclick="fillOutDatesToUpdate('FREE', this.parentElement)">frei</a>
                    </form>
                    <form method="post" th:object="${roomsWrapper}" th:action="@{/rooms/updateroomplan}">
                        <input th:field="*{rooms}" th:value="${rooms}" hidden>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="fillOutDatesToUpdate('BUSY', this.parentElement)">belegt</a>
                    </form>
                    <form method="post" th:object="${roomsWrapper}" th:action="@{/rooms/updateroomplan}">
                        <input th:field="*{rooms}" th:value="${rooms}" hidden>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="fillOutDatesToUpdate('BEING_CLEANED', this.parentElement)">wird geputzt</a>
                    </form>
                    <form method="post" th:object="${roomsWrapper}" th:action="@{/rooms/updateroomplan}">
                        <input th:field="*{rooms}" th:value="${rooms}" hidden>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="fillOutDatesToUpdate('MAINTENANCE', this.parentElement)">Wartung</a>
                    </form>
</div>
```

Function that alters the highlighted/selected rooms on a certain date to the wished status (the rooms I want to change) via the hidden input field I created in the table cells:

```
    function fillOutDatesToUpdate(stateName, parent) {
        $('.highlighted').each(function(){
            $(this).children(":first").val(stateName);
        });
        parent.submit();
    };
```

After submitting the values I receive the wrapper via the model attribute.

```
  @PostMapping(UPDATE_ROOMS_URL)
    public ModelAndView updateRoomStates(@ModelAttribute("roomsWrapper") RoomsRequestWrapper rooms, Model model){
        //manipulation service to be implemented
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + VIEW_ROOMS_URL);
    }
```

Is there any way to submit the changes or is not possible to work with those higher classes in Thymeleaf?

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'at.fhv.team_e.Hotelverwaltung.application.dto.RoomDTO': no matching editors or conversion strategy found` -> How should Spring convert from a String value in your form to a `RoomDTO`? That is just not possible. Your HTML form should have input fields for all fields in your `RoomDTO`.

Comment: But the problem is that I have a list that needs to be sent back. How can I make a hidden input field for that?